# Open source tools to manage Data Quality

Tags: data-warehouse

Are there open source (or commercial) tools that can report data quality issues in a data warehouse using the Kimball star schema model?  It doesn't have to be the silver bullet.  I'm just looking for something to start with that can give basic details of data quality.

Comment: I suspect not. What determines the quality of a given piece of data? Ordinarily, you'd have an ETL process that transforms and loads to your DWH, ditching bad data as it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataCleaner is pretty good (spoken like Larry David)

http://datacleaner.org/

Integrates w Pentaho Data Integration (Kettle) too